# How do I create vertical space between tikz nodes that are duplicated repeatedly?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The block of code below creates a little box to insert words into:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\cvtaga}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,draw=body!50,rounded corners,inner xsep=1ex,inner ysep=0.80ex,text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex,fill=red!10]{#1};
}
```

In another tex file, this will be used multiple times, such as:

```
\cvtaga{Word 1} 
\cvtaga{Word 2}
\cvtaga{Word 3}
\cvtaga{Word 4}
\cvtaga{Word 5}
\cvtaga{Word 6}
\cvtaga{Word 7}
\cvtaga{Word 8}
\cvtaga{Word 9}
```

etc...

This produces a bunch of little boxes with the words inside, and they're separated horizontally by what looks like 1mm, but they're separated vertically by what looks like a line width.

I have tried to add 'outer sep' settings in the node to separate Word 1 through Word 9 by bigger vertical spaces, but no setting has any effect.

How do I control the space between the word boxes?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Each tikz is being treated like a word in a sentence, so the line spacing really is line spacing.  Odds are the top and bottoms are too close for \baselineskip, so \lineskip is added between them.  To increase the spacing, you can either increase \baselineskip (a lot) or \lineskip.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, that was it.  I simply needed to add a \lineskip and a value, and all the boxes separated out vertically just like they were horizontally.  I get now what's happening, with your explanation that this is treating each tikz like a word, complete with regular word spacing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

For better understanding your problem you should provide a small but complete document, which show Your problem. As far as I understand your problem, you like to have a "chain" of nodes with equal vertical distance between the, If this is a case, that try to consider `chains` and `positioning` libraries of `tikz` package, something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1mm,    % or any desired vertical distance between nodes
  start chain = A going below,
     N/.style = {draw=red!50, rounded corners, fill=red!10,
                 inner xsep=1ex, inner ysep=0.80ex,
                 text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex} % be aware, that with this settings width of nodes is accommodated to nodes contents widths
                    ]
     \begin{scope}[nodes={N, on chain=A}]
\node   {Word 1};
\node   {Word 2};
\node   {Word 3};
\node   {Word 4};
\node   {Word 5};
\node   {Word 6};
\node   {Word 7};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In a cese, that you like to connect nodes by arrows, the macro ˙join be of big help:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm,    % or any desired vertical distance between nodes
  start chain = A going below,
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, semithick}, 
     N/.style = {draw=red!50, rounded corners, fill=red!10,
                 inner xsep=1ex, inner ysep=0.80ex,
                 text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex},
                    ]
     \begin{scope}[nodes={N, on chain=A, join=by arr}]
\node   {Word 1};
\node   {Word 2};
\node   {Word 3};
\node   {Word 4};
\node   {Word 5};
\node   {Word 6};
\node   {Word 7};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is not the exact issue I was having, but I will keep this answer for future reference.

Comment: @lightstrong, if not exactly What you like to get, than please make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[image]

with this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[POS/.style={anchor=base,draw=red!50,rounded corners,inner xsep=1ex,inner ysep=0.80ex,text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex,fill=red!10}]
        \node[POS] (w1) {Word1};
        \node[POS] (w2) [below= of w1] {Word2};
        \node[POS] (w3) [below= of w2] {Word3};
        %optional
        \draw[-latex] (w1)--(w2);
        \draw[-latex] (w2)--(w3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I will also keep this code snippet for future reference.

Comment: Normally,if You like the anwer You upvote them, if You accept the anwer You check them...